# How would I specify this function (mathematical formula) in R?

Tags: r, function, math, cdf

I'm new to R, and a formula I need to enter includes functions that are beyond the scope of my mathematics experience. In particular, I don't understand what's going on with the subscript to the gamma function. Is this an incomplete gamma function, and if so, is it upper or lower?

Anyhow, the formula is attached in the image. This is the CDF for the 4 parameter Generalized Gamma distribution, taken from a statistical software manual. How would I specify this in R? Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Generalized Gamma CDF (4P) formula]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be completely wrong, but it seems that function `F` in the image is a combination of an upper incomplete gamma function and other terms. The subscript seems to be a transformation of `x`:

```
y <- ((x - gamma)/beta)^k
```

If so it could be coded as follows.

```
f <- function(x, a, beta, gamma, k){
  y <- ((x - gamma)/beta)^k
  pgamma(y, a, lower = FALSE)*gamma(a)
}
```

The expression

```
pgamma(y, a, lower = FALSE)*gamma(a)
```

is a base R way to code the upper incomplete gamma function. Alternatively, package `gsl`, function `gamma_inc` could be used replacing that code line with

```
gsl::gamma_inc(a, y)
```

Comment: The code is good but it wasn't giving me a CDF. After a bit of trial and error I figured it out. The subscript in the formula specifies the lower incomplete gamma, not the upper. It's not very clear, I researched all over for clues on this type of notation and couldn't find much. Thank you, your answer was very helpful.